# `DummyExecutor` for Python's `futures`

Tags: python, debugging, concurrency, future, concurrent.futures

Python's `futures` package allows us to enjoy `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor` for doing tasks in parallel.

However, for debugging it is sometimes useful to temporarily replace the true parallelism with a dummy one, which carries out the tasks in a serial way in the main thread, without spawning any threads or processes.

Is there anywhere an implementation of a `DummyExecutor`?

Comment: @mata I don't think so, that would create one thread which will still be separate from the main thread.

Comment: of course you're right. but then it should't be too complicated to implement an `Executor` which on submit directly calls the callable and returns a `Future` object. A look a the [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://code.google.com/p/pythonfutures/source/browse/trunk/concurrent/futures/thread.py#98) might help

Comment: It always looks simple before you do it, but not always after you do it. If someone already implemented this, it's much preferable that I use their ready implementation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
from concurrent.futures import Future, Executor
from threading import Lock


class DummyExecutor(Executor):

    def __init__(self):
        self._shutdown = False
        self._shutdownLock = Lock()

    def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        with self._shutdownLock:
            if self._shutdown:
                raise RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after shutdown')

            f = Future()
            try:
                result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            except BaseException as e:
                f.set_exception(e)
            else:
                f.set_result(result)

            return f

    def shutdown(self, wait=True):
        with self._shutdownLock:
            self._shutdown = True


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def fnc(err):
        if err:
            raise Exception("test")
        else:
            return "ok"

    ex = DummyExecutor()
    print(ex.submit(fnc, True))
    print(ex.submit(fnc, False))
    ex.shutdown()
    ex.submit(fnc, True) # raises exception
```

locking is probably not needed in this case, but can't hurt to have it.

Answer (score 4):

Use this to mock your ThreadPoolExecutor

```
class MockThreadPoolExecutor():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        pass

    def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        # execute functions in series without creating threads
        # for easier unit testing
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return result

    def shutdown(self, wait=True):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def sum(a, b):
        return a + b

    with MockThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        future_result = list()
        for i in range(5):
            future_result.append(executor.submit(sum, i + 1, i + 2))
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but I'm using this to test code then does something with the `Future` objects returned by `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit`.  My solution was to also add a small `MockFuture` class with a `result` method, and have `submit` return an instance of that rather than the result directly.

Comment: Coming back to this almost two years later to say that rather than creating a `MockFuture` class, you can have `MockThreadPoolExecutor.submit` create a real `futures.Future` object, call `new_future.set_result`, and then return it, as suggested here: https://bugs.python.org/issue36395  Some library functions, such as `concurrent.futures.as_completed`, look at the internals of the futures, so it can be easier to use the real class than try to mock it.

Answer (score 0):

Pools from `concurrent.futures` package are eager (which you of course want and which means they pick up calculations as soon as possible - some time between `pool.submit()` call and associated `future.result()` method returns).

From perspective of synchronous code you have two choices - either calculate tasks result on `pool.submit()` call, or `future.result()` retrieval.

I find second approach more natural since it better imitates "nonblocking" nature of `pool.map()` from perspective of main thread - results can be obtained one after another as soon as they done calculating (rather then when they are all ready).

Here is my code (additional implementation of `DummyFuture` is needed):

```py
from concurrent.futures import Executor
from threading import Lock
from functools import partial


class DummyFuture():
    def __init__(self, calculation) -> None:
        self.calculation = calculation
    def result(self, timeout=None):
        return self.calculation()
    def cancel(self):
        pass


class DummyExecutor(Executor):

    def __init__(self):
        self._shutdown = False
        self._shutdown_lock = Lock()

    def submit(self, fn, /, *args, **kwargs):
        with self._shutdown_lock:
            if self._shutdown:
                raise RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after shutdown')

            return DummyFuture(partial(fn, *args, **kwargs))

    def shutdown(self, wait=True, *, cancel_futures=False):
        with self._shutdown_lock:
            self._shutdown = True
```

(I have to give credit to mata's answer since it was initial start of my implementation.)